# Rick's technology is apparently no secret nor are his interactions with aliens and his travels into space but Earth seems the same — why?

Tags: rick-and-morty

I am sure the creators would not dignify my question with a response, but am I wrong about no one else on Earth using the technology or traveling into space? It sure seems like somehow Rick has managed to keep all of his technology and discoveries to himself without any kind of secrecy at all.

Comment: Well, he's a tech genius beyond anyone else on Earth.  So, unless he tells others how to build those things, they'll have a hard time figuring out.  That said, the President seems to have some pretty sophisticated stuff, including shrinking technology.  So Rick isn't the only guy with sci fi gadgets.

Comment: Having the genius scientist's inventions somehow not change the world at all is quite common, especially in cartoons. Generally it doesn't get much more than a handwave because an explanation draws attention to things you don't really want the audience to bother themselves with. See also TV Tropes on [why Reed Richards is useless](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ReedRichardsIsUseless).

Comment: If my memory serves well, at least one time they changed the world beyond recognition and repair and "solved" it by switching to another universe which is exactly the same without their mistake and where their other versions die a few minutes before, taking their places. I am not sure if this happened more than once. So I have no idea of how many times the "home universe" of the story telling was switched and by the way how often the Rick and/or the Morty the story telling follows are switched to versions from another universe.

Comment: I don't think it's happened *too* many times, but definitely more than once, as Rick mentioned in one episode what a pain it is to have to relocate like that.

Answer (score 2):

He does not sell gadgets on Earth, so as drawings, so as tools to make things.
And technological gap is wide enough, so knowing does not mean to be able to make it work.(fusion reactor as an example).

And what gives you the idea that they not care or that information is so easily available to anyone. What we see is totaly 180 of that, few do know something, there are some agents under cover which keep their identies secret, some guys at gov know something have something but that all, etc, they are not bragging about things on television, far from that.

And not that many peopole are involved, usually, when it is not an earth doomsday - they aren't deliberatly spreading information and in contrary they do hold things under a table deliberatly.

So as there are different groups which do care when certain technologies are used - those time guys when there was some version splitting, as an example.

The Rick hive mind organization keeps track of things to some extend and they clearly dislike when their authority is challenged, so not likely thya are that keen on spreading all sorts of tech. Who knows which else forces are lurking, including others Rick hive minds.

In the story episode when Rick broke out and destroyed Rick'es forthress, we see different Morties, so as different Ricks and they all conduct business in a different ways.

But the version of Rick, which we are more familiar with, in their house - Passwords access restrictions everywhere, hidden storages, intrusion alarms, infestation alarms, foregn agents wiping out. So, the version of Rick does things in the way.

When those aliens arrived which feeded humans with pils, and those robodogs etc they all were keept at bay. This version of Rick and his Morty like the original smell and feel version of earth, and when they move out due some doomsdays, thay do not select more advanced and futuristic ones, so they do care about those things, for things to be as usual. So as they are protective about their home planet, they are not that willing to let others roam freely and do what they want.

For us, as viewers, their life is a lesser secret, but not for outsiders and they do keep low profile, and fix clean deviations, keep secrets etc. It is the way this version behaves and likes to do business, others do differently and probably there are versions which propel their earth's to the future and the doom, lol, but not this one. The one enslaves words of worlds, and have whole planets/realms for to keep a toilet there. So things are that way because the one likes it that way.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You have some good points, and you cover a lot of cases; the only thing you could do to make this a better answer is add some pointers to specific episodes where, for example, government agencies help keep secrets.

Comment: @DavidW was just passing by, and all by memory. But which part of that answer however lead to 'agencies help' as of out their own intencions, beside their regular mode of operation. And what they probably can do against if he wishes that to be done when he can swap bodies minds etc - it mater of issuing order under disguise, or convincing higherups to do a right things for their own good or mass wipe memories etc etc. There is no end to means, and we see the result of that.

Answer (score 0):

We see, on the episody where bird person weds to Tammy, that several human guests come to the wedding party, so to some extent, at least a bunch of humans knows about space/dimensions and are capable to travel through it, using technology from the Federation of Planets (Tammy is an agent of the FoP, so we can assume there are other agents on the earth) or "taxi services" (I assume this is the way Tammy's parents come to the wedding).

Also, the infinity possibilities of infinity dimensions applies here. There is a 100% probablity that in some dimension there are other people using and traveling through dimensions with Rick's technology or with other technology developed by them, and if this happen in one dimension, those people travel to other dimensions, and eventually will permeate their knowledge and/or technology to other people. So... probably is cooler for the script to maintain portal technology only on Rick's hands, but is statistically impossible.

Answer (score 0):

In the show, it's seen that the US government have advanced technology. But they are second to Rick, and far behind. They just want to keep Rick on their side for problem-solving and hide stuff from the public.

Most aliens don't give a damn about Earth until they conquest Earth so from that point is hard to make up excuses. The most important thing is that it's not really important to the show, it's not hard Sci-fi and complex but is loose and fun.

Comment: I've made some fixes to spelling and grammar.  Please check that I haven't changed the meaning of the answer.